# ItemsControl missing vertical scrollbar

Tags: wpf, xaml, scroll, itemscontrol

I have the below `ItemsControl` which wraps items perfectly but it does not have a vertical scrollbar to see the wrapped items. How can I get the scrollbar to show?

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="tStack" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Shows.View}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  BorderThickness="0.5">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="250">
                    <Controls1:MyShowsUserControl Padding="10"/>
                </Viewbox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`ItemsControl` by default does not wrap `ItemsPresenter` in `ScrollViewer` so you have to do it manually like so:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
   <ItemsControl x:Name="tStack" ... >
      <!-- .... -->
   </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Very strange... I tried it 20x before and it didn't work and now it does... Thank you!

Comment: I figured out the problem: if I enter a value for the horizontal scrollbar visibility of the scrollviewer then it doesn't work properly

Comment: If this is not working, please add height of parent element of scrollviewer.

<Grid Height = "1020">
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollbarVisibility="Auto">
<ItemsControl>
...
</ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
</Grid>

Answer (score 8):

Wrap your `ItemsControl` in a `ScrollViewer` control.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <ItemsControl ...
</ScrollViewer>
```

Remember to put the `Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"` attributes in the ScrollViewer instead of in your ItemControl.

Answer (score 0):

Use ScrollViewer and set the property "VerticalScrollBarVisibility" true.

< ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

Here your ItemsControl

< /ScrollViewer>